# Where should instance variables in a class in Python be placed?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, python-3.x

It's clear that, in Python, class-level or static variables are neither declared within constructors/methods nor are they accessed through "self." ([this explains it better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python/68672#68672)).

However, I am confused as to where instance variables should be declared/stored within the class.

It seems messy and potentially difficult to keep track of all of a class' instance variables if they are declared through different methods, and I wanted to learn the "Pythonic" way to do it. Is it to declare all of them in the constructor and set them to Null, only to be modified later?

Thank you!

Comment: It *seems* like your question was [answered on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254576/is-it-a-good-practice-to-declare-instance-variables-as-none-in-a-class-in-python).

Comment: If you expect to have instance variables it makes perfect sense to put them in __init__ method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

- Class attributes *are* accessible through `self`.  If python doesn't find an attribute on the instance `self`, it will begin searching on `type(self)` etc.
- If you think it would improve clarity to set the most common instance attributes to `None`, you should do that in `__init__`.